# Bones make objects scale and shrink

Tags: objects, bones

I created a simple Stick Figure, and I intended to rig it and make a animation resembling a 2D drawing. But I am not very good at rigging, and I cannot figure out why after an object is attatched to a bone, when I rotate it, the object shrinks as it rotates. The object also does not move exactly with the bones. I have no clue how to fix this, and the tutorials I use don't have any explanation.
[image: Bones and Figure]
[image: Not working]
The Blue is about how it should be positioned, and the red it what it actually does.
[image: Thats how it should look, but it doesn't]

[image]

Comment: It looks like your weight painting isn't correct, could you please [post your .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) here?  Or at least show some screenshots of the weight painting.

Comment: Added, @PGmath. I forget that that is available sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (probably) because your mesh isn't correctly assigned to your rig.

Each vertex needs to know which bone(s) to follow, and how much. If you've got one vertex assigned to two bones, then that vertex will do a combination of what both bones are doing. If you've got a vertex that's only assigned to one bone, but only at 50%, then it'll only move/rotate/scale half as much as the bone does.

To check this, go into pose mode and then from there directly into weight paint mode and check the colors of the mesh as you select each bone. Blue is zero, red is one. Zero means that vertex will not follow the selected bone at all. Red means it'll follow that bone 100%. Somewhere in between will do some combination.

You can use the painting tools to modify this, but they are also just vertex groups. You can use normal vertex group assignments to assign vertices to a given bone. With a mesh as simple as yours, that might actually be easier.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It still is not following the bone 100%, even when all vertices I want are red, and all those I don't are blue. It gets pulled toward it, but not right on it... I thought I followed the tutorial exactly, but this always happens to me.

Comment: Aha! I found one of the bones had been selected for the whole thing. That was throwing the whole thing out of wack. You were right. Thanks!